# Github repo structure advice

Tags: git, github, workflow

I've been looking to setup a commit triage.

To describe with an example:
[image]

Would it be possible to make commits from the core repo trickle down to the production repo and commits to the production repo to trickle down to the Webproject repo's ?
Has anyone have experience running setups like this ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "make commits trickle down"? Should the downstream repos have the same state as Core eventually?

Comment: Yes the downstream repos should recieve the same commits as pushed to the Core repo

Comment: Why do they have to be separate repos to begin with then?

Comment: Some of the static hosting providers only allow a repository to hooked.

Comment: I meant to ask, are the downstream repos identical, or do they contain commits on top of what you have from core?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry misinterpreted they would contain their own commits on top of the ones coming from core, as far as i understand this would be possible with branches but with repo's its not that straight forward.

Comment: You could make them forks of the core repo and then use the [GitHub sync](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/syncing-a-fork) functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible avenue would be to use a GitHub Action on your first repository, like [Git Repository Sync](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/git-repository-sync).

That would allow you to pushes all commits in the branch that this action is run on into any remote git repository.
Your commits would then be "propagated" to other repositories.

Comment: That looks like what i was thinking of but what would be the difference between benjamin's answer of using syncing a fork ? or would this act the same as setting up an action

Comment: @KevinG The idea is to avoid a fork if you don't need one, to better isolate the public repo from its private upstream repository.